# How to change capcha script with ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

sorry if this is too easy to master. i have this code **index.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.realperson.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.plugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.realperson.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('#defaultReal').realperson();
});
</script>

<div id="lalala">
</div>
    <form action="jquery.realperson.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="defaultReal" name="defaultReal">
        <p style="clear: both;">
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="submit" class="Submit" value="Submit">
        </p>
    </form>
```

and this **jquery.realperson.php**

```
<?php
function rpHash($value) {
    $hash = 5381;
    $value = strtoupper($value);
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($value); $i++) {
        $hash = (($hash << 5) + $hash) + ord(substr($value, $i));
    }
    return $hash;
}
if (rpHash($_POST['defaultReal']) == $_POST['defaultRealHash']) {
echo 'OK';
} else {
echo 'NO';
}
?>
```

so I wanted to make like this. to call php

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "jquery.realperson.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
    if (html == 'OK') {
        $("#lalala").html("ok");
    } else {
        $("#lalala").html("no");
    }
});
```

how do I make with ajax ? because if I use the above, I moved the page to **jquery.realperson.php**. so I would like to be kept on **index.html**... i get this code form http://keith-wood.name/realPerson.html

Answer (score 1):

Call the ajax when the form is submitted and cancel the default behavior of the submit.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    type: this.method, // use the method specified in the form
    url: this.action, // use the url (action) specified in the form
    data: dataString, // dataString is currently undefined
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
      if (html == 'OK') {
        $("#lalala").html("ok");
      } else {
        $("#lalala").html("no");
      }
    }
  });

});
```

Your code currently uses an undefined `dataString` variable which you will need to fix for the code to work correctly.

Comment: you should set `data` like this `data: $(this).serialize(),`